# Inference error using negated truthy/falsy narrowing

Tags: typescript

When using TypeScript in VS Code, I am unable to infer a type from a union of objects by using negated truthy/falsy narrowing.

Take the following example:

```
// object union type
export type Result = { ok: true; value: 'foo' } | { ok: false; error: 'bar' };

const resolve = (): Result => ({ ok: false, error: 'bar'});
const result = resolve();

// narrowing on my machine works fine without negation
if (result.ok) console.log(result.value)

// narrowing with negation causes an error
if (!result.ok) console.log(result.error)
```

The error I am getting is: `Property 'error' does not exist on type '{ ok: true; value: void; }` - implying that the union type is not being narrowed by the if statement and that no inference is occurring.

This is unusual because in other environments, this type of narrowing does work, [such as in this sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKwDOBXANvAXjgG84IBrALgSm2AG44A3AQ1zuoHIAzCCTuAF84AHxJkqcbm0wM4wKFGhcARiygDB9AFDaAxhAB2meFCwRcTVEQAUASmoYc%20OAQB8cG6QrVpuWQA08orKcJxqGoJ2OvpGJnBmzoQJ5pbA9jEAltyeAISJeDAAdBR2cNpwcAbGFsBFuBAA5jYF%20EUKSlB22kA) where negated truthy/falsy narrowing works fine.

So the issue must be my environment, but what in my environment could be causing TypeScript to behave abnormally like this? And more specifically - how can I fix my TypeScript narrowing?

Details about my environment:

- It's an NX project, using `"typescript": "4.7.4"`
- VS Code settings.json: `"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"`
- machine: macOS, 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel i9

Comment: Are you sure your real example is exactly the same as above? The only thing I can think of your  `ok` property union may contain values like `undefined` or `null` then your negated check won't work as both  `undefined` and `null` are falsy values.

Comment: The missing error might be caused by not having `"strictNullChecks": true` (or `"strict": true`) in the `"compilerOptions"` of your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: THANK YOU! My problem was solved by setting both `"strictNullChecks"` &  `"strict"` to `true` in my tsconfig.json file. Incredible. I was just beginning to think it was a tsconfig issue. I am in your debt!!

Answer (score 0):

Without more exhaustive information about your IDE environment, I can only make guesses. However, I think you can solve this issue of property accessibility while still maintaining type safety without making changes there.

When dealing with a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions), the typical approach is what you showed: `A | B`. But another way to approach it is to include all properties from both types in each type, and to set the unique properties of each type as optional and `never` on the other.

Here's an example of how to do that using a couple of type utilities:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggcge2AIQDwwDRWQPigXligDIoAFAQwCdgBLCgG1QCUIBjBKgE1QFEAPNgwCuXCKgDWEEAgBm2LFJnyYOLADsIANwhUcOANwAoUJFgB5KmkzY8heEmtZcUAD6xEKVMiyrjJ8GhzAGlWAGdhBmACKABvKAQJAC4oYCphCAMoLUYMlIByWQQEfKgAX2NTaDgQ8MjownjElNlGMMyoXSpOAoAjalKKgLM6qJiYSzRaiAiorBrQmfrDIyMxIWpoDnUw6KolqJTR4H9aeQAKfdngADpEgEo4oygoK-q7iWMX75eAel+AHoAfmerwOty6nC+Pz+gJBLzeURuOREmVBMP+wKMZVWZyg5wAhIjbg8ngjwR9oRi4aDiTdIVQqT9MfCwddkbk0TDYVicUA)

```ts
type ANotB<A, B> = A & Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof B, keyof A>, never>>;
type AOrB<A, B> = ANotB<A, B> | ANotB<B, A>;

type OKResult = { ok: true; value: 'foo' };
type NOKResult = { ok: false; error: 'bar' };
type Result = AOrB<OKResult, NOKResult>;

declare const result: Result;

if (result.ok) {
  result.ok;
       //^? (property) ok: true
  result.error;
       //^? (property) error?: undefined
  result.value;
       //^? (property) value: "foo"
}

if (!result.ok) {
  result.ok;
       //^? (property) ok: false
  result.error;
       //^? (property) error: "bar"
  result.value;
       //^? (property) value?: undefined
}
```

Using this approach, TypeScript does not prevent you from accessing properties using [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#dot_notation) which might only be in the other union type. When using the traditional approach, one must use the `in` operator first to inform the compiler that the property exists.